# Do sephardim have different halachas for serving cholent from a blech on shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul

I always learned that it's forbidden to, for example, stir cholent while it's still on the blech/hot plate on shabbos, or to serve it straight from the blech/hot plate. Rather, one must remove the pot from the blech/hot plate first with the intention of returning it to the blech/hot plate.

I have some family through marriage who observe some Sephardic customs, and they both stir the cholent while on the blech/hot plate, and also serve it straight from the blech/hot plate. When I've asked them about it, they say Sephardic halacha is different. I haven't been able to find any source which *does* allow it, and I'm curious what the source is, or if someone is confused?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.318.18?lang=bi

Comment: Yes they do. Check out this link: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bishul#Saving_a_Burning_Cholent

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Uri and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Yes if ashkenazim knew what we sefardim do in our kitchens, they'd be appalled!

Comment: @RabbiKaii We do and we are 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to serving the food from a pot on the fire, and assuming the food is fully cooked, then it seems that Beit Yosef permits this. (See e.g. [Mishnah Berurah 318:113](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.318.113?lang=bi).)

Stirring the pot while it is on the fire is more controversial. [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef 318:46](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_23.html#HtmpReportNum0105_L2) does not allow one to stir the pot on the fire, as it looks like cooking, even if the food is fully cooked. However, on an electric hot plate (*plata*) is is permitted to stir the pot when the food is fully cooked. (I presume because it doesn't look like cooking when it's on a *plata*.)

It should be noted that [Chazon Ish Orach Chaim 37:15](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14336&st=&pgnum=107) writes that according to those who permit serving from a fully cooked pot on the fire, stirring should also be permitted.

The above is all to explain Sefardic practice. In general, even if the food is fully cooked, Ashkenazim would be more stringent and take the food off the fire before serving, and even then some would be stringent not to stir but only to serve. (See e.g. [Mishnah Berurah 318:117](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.318.117?lang=bi).)